# Wrong project in Google SDK

Tags: api, google-app-engine

I want to build a TTS application and I am using the Google TTS engine. However, when trying the examples such as

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data "{
  'input':{
    'text':'I\'ve added the event to your calendar.'
  },
  'voice':{
    'languageCode':'en-gb',
    'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
    'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
  },
  'audioConfig':{
    'audioEncoding':'MP3'
  }
}" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize"
```

I get Error code 403 telling me that `Cloud Text-to-Speech API has not been used in project 32555940559 before or it is disabled.` Now the problem is that it mentions the project number 32555... but I want to use another project which has the TTS API switched on. Now you might suggest that I switch to the correct project, but I have done that -- when I type `gcloud config list`, it tells me that I am using the correct project (with project number different from the 32555...).

Where is the problem? Why is it trying to use a different project from the one that I am currently using?

Comment: I am almost 100% sure that it has something to do with the service account you are using. I don't think they can be shared between projects, so if you are using one from the other project the API is going to assume you are referring to the project from that account. Have you tried switching to an account from the project with the TTS API enabled?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use "gcloud auth **app-default** print-access-token" (and use a dedicated service account as specified in the docs).

32555940559 is a `CLOUDSDK_CLIENT_ID` that comes with `gcloud`. And app-default has its own client_id as well. It's still now clear how Google API distinguishes between the two, unless it checks for hard-coded app-default client ID (from gcloud SDK).

It's also not clear how gcloud command line still manages to use speech API without a dedicated service account.

Answer (score 1):

On a related note, since I had this same issue (`API has not been used in project  before or it is disabled "32555940559"`) in a Python virtual environment using gcloud SDKs (not curl).

Solved by running:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

(using `gcloud auth login` did not solve it).

For `gcloud`, the root cause might also be related to missing:
`GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` or `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variables.